# Showing an inequality in the real positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

I want to show that $\forall c>0$:

$$0<\left(1-\frac{(wl)^2}{r^2+(wl)^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{wrl}{r^2+(wl)^2}\right)^2<(1-w^2lc)^2+(wrc)^2\tag1$$

Where all variables are bigger than zero.

---

**My work.** If we simplify the middle term I get: $$\frac{r^2}{r^2+(wl)^2}$$ So we need to show $$0<\frac{r^2}{r^2+(wl)^2}<(1-w^2lc)^2+(wrc)^2$$

But what can I conclude from this?

Comment: what is $c$ in the RHS of (1) ?

Comment: @Surb $c$ is a constant bigger than zero.

Comment: Did you mean show that $wrl > r^2 + (wl)^2$

Comment: @ZeroPancakes no, not specifically. I just want to show that $(1)$ is true for all $c>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=r^2+w^2l^2$. The expression is clearly greater than $0$, so consider just the RH inequality.

The central terms can be simplified:
$$\left(1-\frac{(wl)^2}{r^2+(wl)^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{wrl}{r^2+(wl)^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{r^2}{X}\right)^2+\left(\frac{wrl}{X}\right)^2=\frac{r^2}{X}=1-\frac{w^2l^2}{X}.$$
The RH tems can also be simplified:
$$1-2w^2lc+w^4l^2c^2+w^2r^2c^2=1-2w^2lc+w^2c^2X$$

We now need to prove $$-\frac{w^2l^2}{X}<-2w^2lc+w^2c^2X$$

This simplifies to
$$w^2(l^2-2lcX+c^2X^2)>0.$$

The LHS is $w^2(l-cX)^2$ and so the result is true unless $l=c(r^2+w^2l^2)$.

Comment: If we simplify the middle term I get: $$\frac{r^2}{r^2+(wl)^2}$$ So we need to show $$0<\frac{r^2}{r^2+(wl)^2}<(1-w^2lc)^2+(wrc)^2$$ And I do not see how you did that?!

Comment: Your middle fraction is correct. It's easier to deal with  if you write it as shown and expand the RHS before multiplying by X.